# Maximum characters in labels (table names, columns etc)

Tags: postgresql, keyword, identifier

Hope this question wasn't asked before. Does anyone know the character limit for domain names?
For example if I write this:

```
CREATE DOMAIN d_complement_activite_etablissement AS character varying
```

it will create a domain with the name:

```
d_complement_activite_etabliss
```

(Yeah, I know how to count, but I want some more info on the subject).

Is there a command that can change this maximum length? Is this length the same for other names (columns, tables etc)?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You ask:

> Is there a command that can change this maximum length? Is this length
> the same for other names (columns, tables etc)?

The [manual answers here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> The system uses no more than `NAMEDATALEN-1` bytes of an identifier;
> longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated.
> By default, `NAMEDATALEN` is 64 so the maximum identifier length is **63 bytes**. If this limit is problematic, it can be raised by changing the
> `NAMEDATALEN` constant in `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`.

Bold emphasis mine.

The only way to change it is to hack the source code and recompile PostgreSQL.
Domain names are identifiers like any other. When I execute:

```
CREATE DOMAIN d_complement_activite_etablissement_or_even_loger_than_that AS text
```

I get what I ordered (tested on PostgreSQL 8.4 - 11):

```
d_complement_activite_etablissement_or_even_loger_than_that
```

There must be some other piece of software between you and your database cropping the name.

Note that characters in UTF encoding occupy **1 to 4 bytes**. (But ASCII characters (like used in the example) are encoded with a single byte.)

Comment: hmm... that's strange. It now works for me too. I use Postgre 9.1 and ran the command from pgAdmin. Thanks

Comment: @FlorinVistig: The SQL Editor of pgAdmin has a nice feature: When you select part of the code before executing, only the **selected part** gets executed, ignoring everything else. You are aware of it, right? Sounds like you tripped over that.

Comment: I didn't knew about that feature. But I've worked more on SQL Server where that feature exists, and I know to stay away from it. Don't know what was the reason...

Comment: Please note that manual says 63 BYTES, not characters. This means that, for non-ASCII characters, identifiers are truncated after about 31 characters