# How long can PostgreSQL table names be?

Tags: postgresql

I'm planning to use prefixes for a series of database names and need to make sure I don't run into a length limit. What length of table names does PostgreSQL support?

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum characters in labels (table names, columns etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213127/maximum-characters-in-labels-table-names-columns-etc)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> *identifiers*…identify names of tables, columns, or other database objects.…
>
> The system uses no more than `NAMEDATALEN-1` bytes of an identifier; longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated. By default, `NAMEDATALEN` is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63 bytes.

You can see this limit using the query suggested by [this comment](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/173095-table-name-lengths#post672748): `SELECT length(repeat('xyzzy', 100)::NAME);` creates a 500-character string and casts it to PostgreSQL's `NAME` type, then checks the length. The result is `63`.

Comment: Big props for the weird query portion of your answer