# Strapi - Migrating From sqlite to postgres

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I have a strapi project that I have created and developed on sqlite. I however need to migrate it to Postgres db for production. I am getting an error of conflicting keys. I could recreate the project with postgres DB but, if I get assistance with fixing this I would not go through the struggle of starting all over again.
Error details attachched

```
||   error: create index "delivery_service_types_shop_required_verifications_links_order_inv_fk" on "public"."delivery_service_types_shop_required_verifications_links"
││   ("delivery_service_type_order") - relation "delivery_service_types_shop_required_verifications_links_order_" already exists
```

Comment: Postgres limits the size of names to 63 characters, unless you rebuild it with a larger limit.  Your names are larger, so they get truncated.   [How long can PostgreSQL table names be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865770/how-long-can-postgresql-table-names-be)

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. I renamed my collectionName with shorter strings and it worked.