# Function to return dynamic set of columns for given table

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a `fields` table to store column information for other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.fields (
   schema_name varchar(100), 
   table_name  varchar(100), 
   column_text varchar(100), 
   column_name varchar(100), 
   column_type varchar(100) default 'varchar(100)', 
   column_visible boolean
);
```

And I'd like to create a function to fetch data for a specific table.
Just tried sth like this:

```
create or replace function public.get_table(schema_name text,
                                            table_name text,
                                            active boolean default true)
  returns setof record as $$

declare 
    entity_name text default schema_name || '.' || table_name;
    r record;
begin
    for r in EXECUTE 'select * from ' || entity_name loop
        return next r;
    end loop;
    return;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

With this function I have to specify columns when I call it!

```
select * from public.get_table('public', 'users') as dept(id int, uname text);
```

I want to pass `schema_name` and `table_name` as parameters to function and get record list, according to `column_visible` field in `public.fields` table.

Comment: Please ask your added question as new question. (You can always link to this one if it's related.) I rolled back your last edit, you can see revisions in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41644680/revisions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Solution for the simple case

As explained in the referenced answers below, you can use registered (row) types, and thus implicitly declare the return type of a polymorphic function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_table(_tbl_type anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('TABLE %s', pg_typeof(_tbl_type));
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_table(NULL::public.users);  -- note the syntax!
```

Returns the complete table (with all user columns).

**Wait! How?**

Detailed explanation in this related answer, chapter
*"Various complete table types"*:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

`TABLE foo` is just short for `SELECT * FROM foo`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

#### *2* steps for completely dynamic return type

But what you are trying to do is ***strictly impossible*** in a *single* SQL command.

> *I want to pass `schema_name` and `table_name` as parameters to function and get record list, according to `column_visible` field in
> `public.fields` table.*

There is no direct way to return an arbitrary selection of columns (return type not known at call time) from a function - or *any* SQL command. SQL demands to know number, names and types of resulting columns at call time. More in the 2nd chapter of this related answer:

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159286/3684)

There are various ***workarounds***. You could wrap the result in one of the standard document types (`json`, `jsonb`, `hstore`, `xml`).

***Or*** you generate the query with one function call and execute the result with the next:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_get_table(_schema_name text, _table_name text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
   SELECT format('SELECT %s FROM %I.%I'
               , string_agg(quote_ident(column_name), ', ')
               , schema_name
               , table_name)
   FROM   fields
   WHERE  column_visible
   AND    schema_name = _schema_name 
   AND    table_name  = _table_name
   GROUP  BY schema_name, table_name
   ORDER  BY schema_name, table_name;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT public.generate_get_table('public', 'users');
```

This create a query of the form:

```
SELECT usr_id, usr FROM public.users;
```

Execute it in the 2nd step. (You might want to add column numbers and order columns.)
Or append `\gexec` in psql to execute the return value immediately. See:

[How to force evaluation of subquery before joining / pushing down to foreign server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492561/how-to-force-evaluation-of-subquery-before-joining-pushing-down-to-foreign-ser/61493138#61493138)

Be sure to defend against SQL injection:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

Asides

`varchar(100)` does not make much sense for identifiers, which are limited to 63 characters in standard Postgres:

- [Maximum characters in labels (table names, columns etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213127/maximum-characters-in-labels-table-names-columns-etc/8218026#8218026)

If you understand how the object identifier type `regclass` works, you might replace schema and table name with a singe `regclass` column.

Comment: great answer as always! you have a typo: `pg_temp.get_table` supposed to be `public.get_table`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: Yes, thank you. That was a spillover from my test environment. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need another query to get the list of columns you want.

Maybe something like (this is untested):

```
create or replace function public.get_table(_schema_name text, _table_name text, active boolean default true) returns setof record as $$
declare
    entity_name text default schema_name || '.' || table_name;
    r record;
    columns varchar;
begin
    -- Get the list of columns
    SELECT string_agg(column_name, ', ')
         INTO columns
         FROM public.fields
         WHERE fields.schema_name = _schema_name
            AND fields.table_name = _table_name
            AND fields.column_visible = TRUE;

    -- Return rows from the specified table
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select ' || columns || ' from ' || entity_name;

    RETURN;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Keep in mind that column/table references may need to be surrounded by double quotes if they have certain characters in them.

Comment: Still returning anonymous records, you are still required to add a column definition list to every call.

Comment: The initial question sounded like he was having problems getting the SQL to generate the list of columns, but I may have misunderstood.