# Postgresql: How to return a table with a different number of columns depending on an if statement

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to return different table structure depending on where it falls in the if statement.

```
if statement then
return table(col1,col2) 
elsif statement then
return table(col1,col2,col3)
```

Or how else would I be able to return something alike?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to return dynamic set of columns for given table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644680/function-to-return-dynamic-set-of-columns-for-given-table)

Comment: Is this within a function?