# Using a parameter as return type in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql

Say I have this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_from_table(table_name varchar(63))
  RETURNS SETOF table_name AS
$$
DECLARE
    query TEXT := 'SELECT * FROM ' || table_name;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now if I try to execute it, I get `error: type "table_name" does not exist` and that's probably because I can only use the parameters within the function (between the dollar quotes) and not in the return type definition.

The question would be: are there any ways to `SELECT` from a table by passing its name as a parameter instead of hard coding it to the function? How?

Comment: Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644680/function-to-return-dynamic-set-of-columns-for-given-table/41646611#41646611 If this related answer does not answer your question, please clarify what else you need.

Comment: It might be the right answer, maybe I will test it latter. Though to solve this problem I've made a `table` class that loads up a template `sql` file and compiles it (using a templating library) with a table name, identifiers and other unique table parameters. That made the queries faster and less vulnerable to injections. Also using this method I avoided functions for simple queries and used prepared statements instead. It's actually not so much of an `postgresql` solution, so I guess it doesn't fit this question as an answer.