# Can I configure Aurora DB max identifier length? How?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have column names that are very long, regardless of the reason for this, I need to store very large names for columns (At least 128), and very large rows overall because of this

[mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html) has a strong limit of 64 for columns and 65,535 for rows

[postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html) has a "configurable" limit of 63 for columns and couldn't find one for rows

My question is this:
AWS Aurora offers both DBs, I've been researching and couldn't find whether this limit is configurable in their postgresql product, is it? How can I change this configuration?

Comment: You might get better answers over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default maximum length for all **PostgreSQL** identifiers (not just columns names) is 63 bytes (not characters). This *can* be changed, like [the manual informs where you linked](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html):

> can be increased by recompiling PostgreSQL

Or in [more detail here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> The system uses no more than `NAMEDATALEN-1` bytes of an identifier;
>   longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated.
>   By default, `NAMEDATALEN` is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63
>   bytes. If this limit is problematic, it can be raised by changing the
>   `NAMEDATALEN` constant in `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`.

Related:

- [Maximum characters in labels (table names, columns etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213127/maximum-characters-in-labels-table-names-columns-etc/8218026#8218026)

So while regular PostgreSQL can be adjusted by editing the source and compiling, this is obviously **not an option**  for a hosted service like Amazon Aurora Postgres. So, no, you cannot change this limit.

There is no maximum length for the sum of all column names of a table in Postgres. There is a **maximum number of columns** though. 1600 or less, depending on data types. Details:

- [What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query)

Answer (score 1):

Stack:
`Nestjs`
`Typeorm`
`Postgres Aurora (AWS Service)`

Hopefully, this helps others. In my case, I cannot reconfigure my Postgres instance because I use AWS. My solution was to shorten the Alias names for my eager-loaded relationships which were over 63 characters. I use the `SnakeNamingStrategy` for Typeorm which might be creating more issues as well. Instead of removing it, I extended it and wrote an overwriting function for eager-loaded aliases.

Here is my solution:

`// short-snake-naming.strategy.ts`

```ts
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from "typeorm-naming-strategies";
import { NamingStrategyInterface } from "typeorm";

export class ShortSnakeNamingStrategy
  extends SnakeNamingStrategy
  implements NamingStrategyInterface
{
  eagerJoinRelationAlias(alias: string, propertyPath: string): string {
    return `${alias.replace(
      /[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)*/g,
      (w) => `${w[0]}_`
    )}_${propertyPath}`;
  }
}
```

`// read-database.configuration.ts`

```ts
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from "typeorm-naming-strategies";
import { ShortSnakeNamingStrategy } from "./short-snake-naming.strategy";

export class ReadDatabaseConfiguration implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions | Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
    return {
      name: "read",
      type: "postgres",
      ...

      namingStrategy: new ShortSnakeNamingStrategy(),
    };
  }
}
```

The `ShortSnakeNamingStrategy` Class takes each eager-loaded relationship and shortens its name from `Product__change_log___auth_user___roles__permissions` to `P_____c____a___r__permissions`

So far this has generated no collisions and kept it below the 63 character max index length.