# Postgresql : Database Object Maximum Limits

Tags: postgresql

I was reading about maximum limits of database objects in Postgres. From [PostgreSQL Limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html):

[image]

My question here is what is the meaning of "can be increased by recompiling PostgreSQL"?

Comment: It means that it's a constant in the code of postgres, and since that's open source you can change the constant yourself and compile a custom version for usage with increased limits.

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no way to update these limit from within Postgres while running—in other words, there is no Postgres command to change any of these values. Instead you'll have to change parameters at a higher level and then recompile Postgres to see the changes take effect. This is likely because these limits (in at least some cases) are set by constant values so the only way to change their value is to change the source then recompile.

In [this answer about changing the maximum identifier length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218026/8068625), the only way to change the max identifier length limit is to manually change the value of a constant in a config file, then recompile Postgres in order for the changes to take effect.

If you're using a managed cloud solution (like Amazon Aurora), this means you will not be able to change these constraints, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60982386/8068625).

Comment: ...we are using postgres aurora...i dont think we can have this kind of .config file changes done?

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's possible to change these values in Aurora (related: [Can I configure Aurora DB max identifier length? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981723/can-i-configure-aurora-db-max-identifier-length-how))